# Последовательность выполнения кода python

Tags: python

В задаче необходимо сделать так, чтобы код не выдавал ошибок при вводе некорректных данных. У  меня получается правильный ответ только так:

```
s1 = input("Введите название вакансии: ")
while len(s1)==0:
    s1 = input('Данные некорректны, повторите ввод: ')
else:
        print(s1)
s2 = input("Введите описание вакансии: ")
while len(s2)==0:
    s2 = input('Данные некорректны, повторите ввод: ')
else:
        print('Описание:', s2)
```

Но он все равно не засчитывается, потому что все функции ввода должны быть в 1 строке:

Line 1 differs: out: Введите название вакансии: Программист corr: Введите название вакансии: Введите описание вакансии

При использовании

```
s1, s2 = input("Введите название вакансии: "), input("Введите описание вакансии: ")
```

фраза 'Данные некорректны, повторите ввод' выводится только для последнего введенного пользователем значения. В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: `while len(x:=input('c'))==0 or len(x2:=input('2'))==0: print(err)`

Comment: проблема в том, что после этого еще идет блок кода, где не нужна проверка, а потом  
`if b1.lower() in ['да', 'нет']:
    print('Свободный график:', b1)
else:
    b1 = input('Данные некорректны, повторите ввод')
if b2.lower() in ['да', 'нет']:
    print('Премиум-вакансия:', b2)
else:
    b2 = input('Данные некорректны, повторите ввод')`
мне не надо выводить ошибку, нужно, чтобы при введении пользователем некорректного значения запрашивался повторный ввод

Comment: создать пользовательскую функцию, которая будет выполнять все проверки и возвращать тру если все пройдены, и вызывать её в том же вхайл, либо создать сверхсложное условие для вхиле.

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    s1, s2 = input("Введите название вакансии: "), input("Введите описание вакансии: ")
    if s1 and s2:
        break
    print('Данные некорректны, повторите ввод: ')
```